# Problem with gradient on the background of a table swift

Tags: swift, tableview, gradient

I have a tableview with the cells and I want apply a custom gradient. I've searched here but nothing works with my code.

My part of the code where I try to add the gradient

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = "Menú Principal"
        tableView.backgroundView?.aplicarDegradadoDeportes() 
        self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)      
    }
```

This is my function for the gradient

```
 func aplicarDegradadoDeportes() {
        let colorInicio =  UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 59/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        let colorFin = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
     let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = [colorInicio, colorFin]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
    
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
        gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
        
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at:0)
    }
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass and override the `layoutSubviews()` function.

For example like this:

```
class GradientTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    // Property to store the gradient layer
    private var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer?
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        // Check if gradient layer already exists
        if gradientLayer == nil {
            // Set the colors for the gradient
            let colorInicio =  UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 59/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
            let colorFin = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
            
            // Create the gradient layer and set its properties
            gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
            gradientLayer?.colors = [colorInicio, colorFin]
            gradientLayer?.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
            gradientLayer?.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
            gradientLayer?.frame = self.bounds
            
            // Add the gradient layer as a sublayer to the cell's content view
            self.contentView.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer!, at:0)
        }
    }
}
```

In your controller you need the set the cell class to `GradientTableViewCell`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  self.title = "Menú Principal"
  self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)

  // Set the cell class for the table view to be GradientTableViewCell
  self.tableView.register(GradientTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
}
```

In the `cellForRowAt` function of your table data dequeue a `GradientTableViewCell` instead of `UITableViewCell`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  // Dequeue a GradientTableViewCell instead of a UITableViewCell
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! GradientTableViewCell

  // Configure the cell as needed

  return cell
}
```

Now you should be able to set the gradient to the background of the cells

Comment: This will insert a new gradient every time layoutSubviews gets called

Comment: @LeoDabus I changed my Code It checks now if the gradient already exists

Comment: It's a bit different approach I was looking for . but it woks as well. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

The `backgroundView` property of `UITableView` is `nil` by default. So your `aplicarDegradadoDeportes` function is never actually called.

Set a view as the `backgroundView` then it should work.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = "Menú Principal"
    let background = UIView()
    tableView.backgroundView = background
    background.aplicarDegradadoDeportes()
    self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)      
}
```

The only issue is that the tableView will update the size of `backgroundView` as needed but your additional layer may not automatically get resized to match.

One solution is to move the code to setup the background view in `viewWillAppear` or you can override `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and update the layer's frame.

The best solution is to create a custom `UIView` subclass that draws the gradient so it stays up to date as it is sized.

```
class GradientView: UIView {
    var gradient: CALayer!

    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        super.didMoveToSuperview()

        if superview != nil {
            let colorInicio =  UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 59/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
            let colorFin = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
            let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
            gradientLayer.colors = [colorInicio, colorFin]
            gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
            gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
            gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds

            self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at:0)
            gradient = gradientLayer
        }
    }

    override var frame: CGRect {
        didSet {
            gradient?.frame = bounds
        }
    }
}
```

Then your view controller `viewDidLoad` becomes:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.title = "Menú Principal"
    let background = GradientView()
    tableView.backgroundView = background
    self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)      
}
```

Comment: It worked thanks so much, I didn't know that the backgroud It's a nil default propierty